# Calculate $\text{Cov}(\, \, \mid X\mid \, \, , \, \, \mid Y\mid \, \, )$ where $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation

Let two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal  as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
X \\
Y
\end{array}
\right) \sim \text{Normal} \left(
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\mu_x \\
\mu_y
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \rho \\
\rho &  1
\end{array}
\right)
\right),
\end{eqnarray}

where  $\rho >0$.

The question is how to calculate
$$\text{Cov}(\, \, \mid X\mid \, \, , \, \, \mid Y\mid  \, \, )\, \, ?$$

For a special case $\mu_x=\mu_y=0$,

$$\text{Cov}(\, \, \mid X\mid \, \, , \, \, \mid Y\mid  \, \, )=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(
\sqrt{1-\rho^2}+\rho \arcsin (\rho) -1 \right).$$

I know $\mid X \mid$ is a folded normal random variable ([Folded_normal_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution)) so
$$E(\mid X \mid)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_x^2}{2}}+\mu_x \text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu_x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

and

$$E(\mid Y \mid)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_y^2}{2}}+\mu_y \text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu_y}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

But I stuck here:
$$E(\mid X Y\mid)=$$